# How to specify linear model when plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, linear-regression, seaborn

I have a linear model of the form:

Outcome ~ predictor_variable + group

I would like to plot a representation of this, including confidence intervals.

I am able to either plot the model correctly but cannot visualise the confidence intervals. Here I add some regression lines base on predicted values I get out of the fitted model:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
sns.scatterplot(x='predictor', y='true_outcome', hue = 'group', data=df, ax=ax)
sns.regplot(x='predictor,y='predicted_outcome',scatter=False, data = 
            df[df['group']==0], ax=ax)
sns.regplot(x='predictor,y='predicted_outcome',scatter=False, data = 
            df[df['group']==1], ax=ax)
```

[image]

Or I can visualise confidence intervals but the plot does not accurately represent the model, as the two lines are fit independently:

```
sns.lmplot(x='predictor', y='true_outcome',  hue='group', data = df)
```

[image]

I would like some advice as to how to e.g. display appropriate confidence intervals on the first graph, or how to get lmplot to fit my desired model.

Comment: Could you explain the aim of your model?  I think a linear regression is not suitable for your data.   A Machine learning model algorithm is decided by problem and data what we solve.

Comment: The aim is to link a predictor (e.g. brain size) to an outcome (e.g. iq) while accounting for another variable (e.g. brain scanner site). The question however is more about the plotting than the modelling per se